# Load data into chartjs using promises in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, chart.js

I'm work with vuejs and I have a function that returns a promise with data obtained from api. How I can load the data in chart settings?

apiData.js

The api returns an array with labels

```
export default {
    getData : function() {
        var request = require('request-promise');
        return request({
            "method" : "GET",
            "uri" : 'http://localhost:3030/api/historial',
            "json" : true,
            "headers" : { 
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
    }
}
```

chartConfig.js

But when I return the result in 'labels' key the chart does not load. If I change to static array works

```
import apiData from 'apiData.js';

export const contaminacion = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels : apiData.getData()
      .then(function(result){
        return result;
      }),
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Test',
          data: [100, 123, 98, 180,],
          backgroundColor: ['#3B52F0'],
          borderColor: ['#36495d'],
          borderWidth: 3
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            padding: 25,
          }
        }]
      },
      legend: {
        display : false
      },
      maintainAspectRatio: false
    }
  }

  export default contaminacion;
```

Comment: You need to move the apiData.getData() to your component, and import your config in that component too. Then apiData.getData().then(function(result){config.labels = result}). It will work

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because this expression returns a Promise:

```
apiData.getData()
      .then(function(result){
        return result;
      })
```

and you're assigning it to the labels property, which expects an array (not a Promise).
In the 'then' callback, what you should do (instead of simply returning the result) is to assign the result to the relevant data source (in this case: contaminacion.data.labels), and make the UI render the new data (in correlation with the Vue.js API and life-cycle).